# jQuery Validate plugin's invalidHandler counter

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How do I get the jQuery Validate plugin to update the `invalidHandler` error counter when a valid entry is done?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#report-listing-form").validate({
        rules: {
            'listing-report-email': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
                'listing-report-name': {
                required: true
            },
                'listing-report-phone': {
                number: true,
                minlength: 7,
                maxlength: 12
            },
                'contact-msg': {
                required: true,
                maxWords: 1000
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            return false;  // will suppress error messages
        },
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = (errors == 1) ? '1 invalid field.' : errors + ' invalid fields.';

                $("#err_report-listing-form").html(message).addClass("text-error");
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('valid form');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

here is a working example of my code http://jsfiddle.net/4VP9X/12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this link [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), I added the showErrors callback. It was closer, but it only updates when a field format fails, like email or phone number. It didn't seem to work on empty fields.

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
  var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();
  if (errors) {
    var message = (errors == 1) ? '1 invalid field.' : errors + ' invalid fields.';
    $("#err_report-listing-form").html(message).addClass("text-error");
      this.defaultShowErrors();
    }               
  },
```

Comment: This works fine, thank you. I have only a problem with errors of grouped fields. Number of wrong fields works very well, Ive only added an else after your if statement for the last error field message, otherwise it still show on. Problem is that error on one of required fields, within a group, remain active when I correct the wrong input. Everything work well with invalidHandler. Two live examples, try ** fields, only one is required and there is a validation control over tel number submission, with invalidHandler: [link](http://bit.ly/1syvluT) and with showErrors [link](http://bit.ly/Zgjwwv)

Comment: my live version with showErrors works on empty fields, take a look. Link in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

**Quote OP**:

> "How do I get the jQuery Validate plugin to update the `invalidHandler`
>   error counter when a valid entry is done?"

Short answer:  You cannot.

[As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

> **invalidHander**:  "Callback for custom code when an invalid form is **submitted**. Called with a event object as the first argument, and the validator as the second."

In other words, the `invalidHander` callback only fires upon the `submit` event.  You can see this behavior in [your own jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VP9X/12/).  There is no workaround, unless you want to hack the code of the plugin itself.